# Camera Preview Overlay Animation Performance Issue

Tags: android, android-camera, android-animation, zxing, android-camera2

I am wondering how do we do this properly.

I have seen some apps that does this and the animation is smooth.

Above my camera preview.

I put an ImageView, and then I animate the ImageView's bottom margin. But I can see that the animation is laggy and stuttering.

Here is how I do the animation

```
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();

        fromValue = dpToPx(fromValue);
        toValue = dpToPx(toValue);

        final ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(fromValue, toValue);

        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                params.bottomMargin = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                imageView.requestLayout();
            }
        });

        valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(timeInterpolator);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Some time ago I wrote an example emulating a fingerprint scanner with animations. Maybe you can check it out and see if it fits your needs: http://www.6020peaks.com/2015/11/how-to-emulate-a-fingerprint-scanner-in-android-with-animations/